# Is there an extension to railroad diagrams to capture exceptions?

Tags: context-free-grammar, bnf

Railroad diagrams are a popular method to visualize context-free grammars and you can map Backus-Naur Form to these diagrams. But [some variants of BNF](http://www-cgi.uni-regensburg.de/~brf09510/grammartypes.html), for instance [W3C-BNF](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-notation) allow exceptions (as context-free languages are not closed under difference, these exceptions must be regular). I'd like to visualize a grammar with exceptions in a railroad diagram. Should I invent my own extension to the graphical notation or has someone already experimented with this?

Here is an example of a rule with exception (yes, you could also express this particular grammar without exception, but that's not the point):

```
comment := "<!--" (string - "--") "-->"
```

An exception can be any regular grammar. I thought about adding exception connected to non-terminal symbols by some special type of arrow or line (here indicated with exclamation marks):

```
[<] → [!] → [-] → [-] → (string) → [-] → [-] → [>]
                          !
                          ! → [-] → [-] → ↯
```

**P.S:** The grammar was wrong, it should be

```
comment := "<!--" (string - (string "--" string | string "-")) "-->"
```

Maybe the non-intuitive use of negation is one reason why it is little used in formal grammars?

Answer (score 4):

When writing a [Railroad Diagram Generator](http://bottlecaps.de/rr/ui) for W3C grammars recently, I thought for a while about how to represent this, but I could not come up with a solution that I was happy with. Did not find any examples to follow either.

It is not only the set-difference operator, for which there is no graphical equivalent in conventional railroad diagrams. The notation for codepoints, ranges, and complements also does not fit well.

In the end I refrained from extending the model graphically. What I did is draw a terminal box to hold the grammar fragment that has no railroad equivalent in the original notation. For distinguishing this from literal boxes, it is set in italics. Here is an example from the XML recommendation:

[image: XML comment railroad diagram]

The EBNF production was:

```
Comment ::= '<!--' ((Char - '-') | ('-' (Char - '-')))* '-->'
```

**Edit**:

Following Jakob's proposal for a different shape, unresolved EBNF expressions are now shown in a hexagon:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I'd use boxed of different shape for codepoints and ranges. Simple regular expressions can also be put in such a box. So there would be three kinds of boxes: terminal symbols, nonterminal symbols, and pattern symbols. Putting non-terminal symbols in these pattern boxes like your "Char - '-'" is a compromise that could be improved. How about drawing a box that contains a patter in form of other boxes?

Comment: You are right, a terminal box is not quite appropriate, so I changed my generator accordingly.

Comment: Good solution. I extended this to a "difference" box. With differences you can write the grammar more readable, but it may become more difficult to parse: http://imgur.com/inAKK

Comment: OK, but I am still reluctant about adding more diverse graphics, so I prefer to go with the more general approach, to just use a box holding arbitrary unresolved expressions. By the way, you appear to be using different semantics than W3C for the difference operator. The W3C operator is for set-difference, i.e. in W3C notation, your example would read: Char* - (Char* "--" Char*)

Comment: Yes, the general pattern box approach is enough for most cases and better than using normal terminal or non-terminal boxes. Thanks for the correction. How about this one: http://imgur.com/BUg8q? It looks like nobody has proposed a railroad diagram for boolean grammars yet.